# How to use/install python code/file in Juypter notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, hana

I got code file as `data_load_util.py` from Git hub. I'm following some tutorial where this import is being used. Using `Python 3.x` and `Juypter` Notebooks with connection to SAP Hana 2.0 Express Edition.

File location - https://github.com/SAP-samples/hana-ml-samples/blob/master/Python-API/pal/notebooks/data_load_utils.py

**Command I'm using for tutorial:**

```
from hana_ml import dataframe 
from data_load_utils import DataSets, Settings
```

**Error I'm getting:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_load_utils'
```

Since I found this utility `data_load_util.py` as code file but not sure how I use this or attach this to python or `juypter` notebooks so that I can use code and this error will be gone.

Help will be appreciated.

[Link to error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Al7c.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Jupyter` where to look for modules via `sys.path`.

From [this](https://mg.readthedocs.io/importing-local-python-modules-from-jupyter-notebooks/sys-path-in-notebook/path-notebook.html) doc, you can add your module’s sub-directory to Python's path like this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../module-subdirectory'))
```

Then you can simply import it:

```
from data_load_utils import DataSets, Settings
```

Note: Here `module-subdirectory` is the sub-directory that has got `data_load_util.py`.

For alternate methods, please refer [this](https://mg.readthedocs.io/importing-local-python-modules-from-jupyter-notebooks/) doc.

Comment: just posted detail where I got syntax error..do you see any solution?

Comment: @Rubane From the error it seems like now it's able to import `data_load_utils`, otherwise it would have thrown `ModuleNotFoundError`. Error indicates that there's a syntax error within `data_load_utils.py`, you may need to debug that separately and ask it in the form of separate question if needed. You can cross check whether import related issue is sorted out by importing your own sample hello_world.py,  having `print("debugging import method")`

Comment: I'm trying to see if the method you recommended is working by using below code.But getting some error. Can you see if you find some issue in this?

Comment: I created separate question for this as well.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056181/indentation-error-while-importing-python-file-in-juypter-notebook