# Indentation error while importing python file in Juypter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am running simple code mentioned below, but getting `indentation error`. I am using `Python 3.x` and `Juypter` notebook. Help will be appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('C:\dir python util'))

import h
h.my_first_function()
```

In file `h.py`, which is in drive `c:\dir python util` contents are below:

```
def my_first_function():
 print ("my first program of python")
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 5, in import h

File "C:\dir python util\h.py", line 2 print ("my first program of python") ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File "C:\dir python util\h.py", line 2 print ("my first program of python") ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Error indicates that it is simple `indentation error`. You need to maintain the appropriate indentation in the code.

With corrected indentation, it'll be as follows:

```
def my_first_function():
    print ("my first program of python")
```

So `print` statement needs to have 4 spaces rather than one.

Suggest you to go through [this](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) document to get idea about Python's indentation rules, if you don't know that already.